# Alert Dialog on click method not working

Tags: android

I have this code for a simple alert dialog which looks like this.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
private boolean toggle;

//an onCreate method here

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
        switch (item.getItemId()) {       
        case R.id.deleteContact:
            if (selectedContactIndex == -1){
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Please select a contact to delete!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
                return true;
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
            myAlertDialog.setTitle("           Confirm Contact Deletion");
            myAlertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + Contact.contactList.get(selectedContactIndex).getFullName() + "?");

            myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                toggle = true;
            }});

            myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                toggle = false;
            }});

            myAlertDialog.show();
            System.out.println(toggle);
            if (toggle) {
                Contact.contactList.remove(selectedContactIndex);
                for (int i = selectedContactIndex; i < Contact.contactList.size(); i++){
                    Contact.contactList.get(i).setContactNumber(i);
                }
                Contact.totalContacts--;
                selectedContactIndex = -1;
                contactsView.invalidateViews();
            }
    }
```

So the way I've done it is, I have a boolean named toggle. If they click yes then the boolean is set to true and the if statement will be executed which actually deletes the contact. I've used a system.out.print and checked the log cat, and apparently the toggle variable is false even after I click the yes button.

One hypothesis I have is: The default value of a boolean is false, so maybe the onClick method isn't even assigning anything to toggle. But I don't know how to fix this.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks for the answers, I put the contact removal logic in the positive button's onClick method and it's working like I want it! The main thing I took from this is to realize that android doesn't always execute linearly.

Comment: Put println inside click handler to see if it is fired.

Comment: @Mateusz Yep, it is being fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual reason to get `toggle always false` is that all your function execute simultaneously, that before you do any action on dailog, `if statment is also execute`.

Solution@ you execute `if statement` when `toggle=true` and on `Yes` click of dialog toggle set to true, so put your `if statement` on `yes click` of dialog instead outside.

```
AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
            myAlertDialog.setTitle("           Confirm Contact Deletion");
            myAlertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + Contact.contactList.get(selectedContactIndex).getFullName() + "?");

            myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                //toggle = true;
                 //Here will be your if statement.
            }});

            myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
               // toggle = false;
            }});

            myAlertDialog.show();
            System.out.println(toggle);

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your default value is **false** and after deletion of contact you **refresh** your activity than it set your toggle value to false which is changed by you in yes button click

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better if you place the logic inside the onclick listener instead of having an if statement outside it. Try something like this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
     myAlertDialog.setTitle("           Confirm Contact Deletion");
     myAlertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + Contact.contactList.get(selectedContactIndex).getFullName() + "?");

     myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    toggle = true;
                    Contact.contactList.remove(selectedContactIndex);
                for (int i = selectedContactIndex; i < Contact.contactList.size(); i++){
                    Contact.contactList.get(i).setContactNumber(i);
                }
                Contact.totalContacts--;
                selectedContactIndex = -1;
                contactsView.invalidateViews();
     }});

     myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    toggle = false;
     }});


     myAlertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey mate the function in the onclick listener is only called after the user actions by clicking on either yes or no, at that point your code to delete the contact has already been executed, execution of your code isn't linear, the click listener function is called later.

try something like this to get you going in the right direction

```
myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        Contact.contactList.remove(selectedContactIndex);
        for (int i = selectedContactIndex; i < Contact.contactList.size(); i++){
            Contact.contactList.get(i).setContactNumber(i);
        }
        Contact.totalContacts--;
        selectedContactIndex = -1;
        contactsView.invalidateViews();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Declare variable as `private boolean toggle = true;`

Comment: This isn't going to work mate :) It will always delete the user whether or not the user clicks yes